# About remote jobs in Stackoverflow

Tags: professionalism, interviewing, resume, recruitment, human-resources

There are many remote jobs listed in SO, I was wondering how does it work?

For example, I'm in Japan, and applied for a job tagged remote in US. And luckily I passed the interview, so, what's next?

1, sign employment contract?
2, live in Japan and work for them full time?
3, they send money to my Japan bank account?

How does it work?

Comment: Differently for each position. VTC.

Comment: There's remote and there's remote.  Some will mean "in a different state", some may handle international.  There is no single rule as requirements for foreign remote workers vary from country to country, some require remote workers to have the same visas as if they were local, some require the company to have a presence in the remote country, potentially costing the company a lot.  Don't assume as they allow remote that you can be on the other side of the world.  Voting to close as specific to the particular circumstances so not a good fit for the site.

Answer (score 3):

Ask their HR. Depends entirely on the company and their processes. They might have it tagged as "US" because they are only able(or willing?) to handle the finance aspect of someone in the US, because things, without a doubt, get more complicated when you're adding someone abroad to the payroll - I could imagine!

Answer (score 2):

If you passed the interview they will let you know what's next. Relax. They will be working out the best way to deal with your hiring. After which (assuming the job is legitimate) they will contact you on the next step/s.